# Que papel ejecuta el punto (.) dentro de esta expresion regular?

Tags: regex

Miren, estuve leyendo un poco acerca de las expresiones regulares en esta [pagina](https://regexone.com).

En una de las lecciones de la pagina, se nos pide que escribamos una expresion regular que coincida con los 3 primeros strings y no con el ultimo. La pregunta nace por la solucion que por equivocacion saque (el cual es diferente al de la pagina).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Accidentalmente escribi un punto y sin querer saque al parecer otra solucion, el cual no entiendo. Puedo comprender que esta pasando hasta el signo +, pero el punto no se que papel hace en la respuesta.

Quisiera saber como afecta el punto en esta expresion?

Answer (score 1):

El punto es carácter comodín: coincide con cualquier carácter excepto con \n. Ese es el papel del punto en cualquier expresión regular.

Para coincidir con un carácter de punto literal (. o \u002E), debe anteponerle el carácter de escape (.).

Answer (score 1):

1. Dentro de este ejemplo podemos destacar lo siguiente

Si tenemos

```
cat.

896.

?=+.
```

Si hacemos un

```
[cat]+.
```

habrá empate solo con la primer opción por que esta tomando la coincidencia de los 3 primeros caracteres mas la coincidencia del último elemento que es el punto y descarta las otras opciones

2. Si por el contrario hacemos lo siguiente

---

```
[cat]\.
```

Y tenemos como opciones

```
cat.

896.

?=+.

abc1
```

Únicamente nos devolverá una coincidencia con `cat.` pues empata el tercer y último caracter que es *t* además de eso termina en punto entonces la coincidencia se da

3. Incluso si ahora hacemos

   [cat]+.

La única coincidencia volverá a ser

```
cat.
```

Por que es la única opción que contiene los 3 caracteres y además termina en punto

> Entonces observamos que si hacemos uso del `+.` estaremos solicitando
>   la coincidencia de los 3 caracteres mas el hecho de que termine en
>   punto y si hacemos uso de `[cat]\.`  buscamos que termine en punto
>   aunque no necesariamente tenga la coincidencia los 3 caracteres